# Wifi suddenly stopped working after Asus laptop went to sleep mode (Ubuntu 14.04) (Atheros AR9485 ath9k 168c:0032)

Tags: 14.04, wireless, atheros, ath9k

I have set up my brand new Asus laptop (F555L) with Ubuntu 14.04 (as the only OS installed) about two weeks ago. Wifi worked just fine right from the start. Two days ago it suddenly stopped working after the laptop had gone to sleep mode. I have not updated the system nor am I aware of anything else I might have done which could have caused it.

I can still see available wifi networks but no connection to my access point is established. My mobile phone connects to wifi no problem btw so it is no problem with the access point itself

I am not an IT expert (you can tell) so do forgive me if I don't give a perfect description, use the correct terms or provide all necessary details upfront. However I do try to provide some useful info below, please do let me know if you need anything else to look into this. Thank you very much in advance!

Here is the link to my "wireless info" file: 
[link removed after problem has been solved]

Comment: Are there any errors in `dmesg`? Does it work again after rebooting?

Comment: Rebooting does not help, I have tried many times (have also tried rebooting with wifi turned off). I will check dmesg tonight and will post the result here. Thank you for looking into this, much appreciated!

Comment: Do you get the problem with other access points? Could you try rebooting the access point? Also try `echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9kfix.conf > /dev/null` then reboot (if it doesn't work you can remove that file with `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ath9kfix.conf`)

Comment: Thanks ever so much for your help, bain. This last advice of yours seems to have done the trick, I am now connected again to my access point. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ath9k chipsets have problems with hardware encryption. Try:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9kfix.conf > /dev/null
```

then reboot.